# Extra space with figure and input

Tags: spacing

In `aux.tex` I have:

```
\begin{equation}
  x + y
\end{equation}
```

Then, in `main.tex` I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \input{aux.tex}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

The behavior of this document seems to have changed recently. Currently (`pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22`) I see extra whitespace between the equation and the paragraph.

[image: extra ws]

However, on a slightly older version (`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21`) there is what seems to me the correct amount of whitespace.

[image: new ws]

Inlining `aux.tex` yields the correct amount of whitespace and so does adding `\unskip` after `\input`. However, it seems to me that neither of those should have any discernible affect on the output in this situation.

Comment: Can you write a `\showlists` (possibly also with `\showboxdepth=\maxdimen \showboxbreadth=\maxdimen`) right after `\begin{document}` and check the log file? There should be some `\vskip`’s in the log file that indicate what is going on…

Comment: I don't seem to get much output from `\showlists` right after `\begin{document}`, but there is plenty placing it right before `\end{document}`. I've included my output [here](https://pastebin.com/GfZHQSkn).

Comment: The extra vertical space seems to appear only with TeX LIve 2020, not with TL 2021

Comment: Thanks for the link to the log. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to contain anything useful to the current situation. Since this is about float placement, can you try `\tracingpages=1` instead of `\showlists`?

Comment: Sure, [here it is](https://pastebin.com/dThWj31P). Thanks!